# outlook does not recognize one or more names in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to write a simple powershell script to send mails and the code I have written is:

```
$recipients = "'abc@abcd.com', 'def@abcd.com'"

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = $recipients
$Mail.Subject = "Action"
$Mail.Body ="Pay rise please"
$Mail.Send()
```

this is working with one recipient, but once I want to add multiple contacts and run the script, it says

```
Outlook does not recognize one or more names. 
At line:10 char:1
+ $Mail.Send()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I have tried a number of ways to define recipient list by using:

```
"'abc@abcd.com', 'def@abcd.com'"
"abc@abcd.com", "def@abcd.com"
"abc@abcd.com, def@abcd.com"
"<abc@abcd.com>, <def@abcd.com>"
```

nothing worked and returns the same error every time.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Aren't recipients normally separated by a semi-colon ; ?

Comment: I believe that with Outlook, you need to (a) separate the recipients with `;`, not `,`, and (b) do not put the name in single quotes inside the double quotes: `"smith@example.com; jones@example.net"`.

Comment: Why not just use Send-MailMessage?

Comment: tried **"abc@abcd.com;def@abcd.com"** as well. **same error**

Comment: Did you try Send-MailMessage?

Comment: @EBGreen Not everybody wants to use `Send-MailMessage`. For example, I've written a script that gets used daily by a whole team that will, as part of it, pop up an email, insert people on the To and CC lines, change the SendAs address, insert a customized body, set permissions to ReadOnly, and then leave it open on the user's screen for them to insert the PIN number for the user's new SmartCard that they setup before they give the card to the user and manually send the email.

Comment: I understand that you have a need for another method. I'm asking the OP though why the simpler method is not being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Recipients` property's `Add()` method to add multiple recipients to an email if you're using Outlook's ComObject, such as:

```
'abc@abcd.com','def@abcd.com'|ForEach{$Mail.Recipients.Add($_)}
```

Doing this will return the recipient object, which you can then manipulate, such as, if you wanted to put them on the CC line instead of the To line you could do:

```
$Recipients = 'abc@abcd.com','def@abcd.com'|ForEach{$Mail.Recipients.Add($_)}
$Recipients | ForEach{$_.Type = 2}
```

Or resolve the address against the user's address book using the `Resolve()` method.